# ViewModel constructor not executed when page is navigated to, mvvm

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a *PopUp* page I navigate to. The issue I am having is that while debugging the code never executes the constructor. I have other pages in this application which all work fine, as well as another pop up page where the contructor is executed just fine.

I am using Prism Mvvm for `ViewModel` location. I have double checked that all namespaces are correct, all of which you will see below. If anyone has encountered this before please help me out of this one. The view is also registered in my `App.xaml.cs` for *Navigation*

#### View

```
<popup:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:popup="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             xmlns:templates="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views.Templates;assembly=MyApp"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.UserProfileView">
    <ScrollView VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Frame Margin="15"
               BackgroundColor="White">
            <StackLayout IsClippedToBounds="True"
                         Padding="10, 5"
                         Spacing="3">
                <Label Text="Test"/>
                <Button Text="Go Back" Command="{Binding GoBackCommand}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </ScrollView>
</popup:PopupPage>
```

#### ViewModel

```
namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
    public class UserProfileView : BaseViewModel
    {
        private INavigationService _navigationService;
        public DelegateCommand GoBackCommand { get; }
    public UserProfileView(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        GoBackCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => await _navigationService.GoBackAsync());
    }
}
```

#### How I Navigate to the page above

```
private async void NavigateToUserProfileView()
{
    await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("UserProfileView");
}
```

Comment: Why using `async void` and not `async Task` for `NavigateToUserProfileView()`?

Comment: are you sure its not calling the default constructor?

Comment: @steve,you mean that the UserProfileView popuppage don't executes the constructor when you navigate this popuppage? I try to use Rg.Plugins.Popup at my side, but I have any issue when I navigate to PopUpPage, so can you provide your simple that can reproduce this issue here?

Comment: @Nkosi because it is a `DelegateCommand` called from a constructor. That does not affect functionality, but indeed a `Task` is more favourable. Thanks!

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I realised that it is because of a name convention error. I replied to the answer below. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Jason, yeah I'm sure. It simply just loads the view without being attached to any viewmodel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there's a typo in the question, and unless the default convention has been changed, the view model for the view `UserProfileView` should be called `UserProfileViewModel` to be found by the `ViewModelLocator`.

Comment: What a silly mistake, I spent about 2 hours on it. Yes absolutely, I am missing `Model` at the end of the class name. The file name actually has `Model` at the end which is most likely what led me astray.